# Finding the circumcentre

Tags: triangles

Suppose angle ACB is 90°, why is p the circumcentre of triangle ACB? I can only proove that RP is the perpendicular bisector but what is it to do with angle ACB? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Too Easy.. $RP||CB$ So $AP=PB$ and $APC$  isosceles triangle SO $AP=PB=PC$.